# Forward traffic to remote external IP through a specific interface

Tags: linux, networking, ip-routing

**Network Diagram**

[image: Network Diagram]

I have 3 servers with two interfaces each, as shown in the diagram. The servers communicate with each other through the interface `enp1` and to the world through the interface `enp0`. For some reason, the servers can not communicate over `enp0`. When I ping from server A to *public.ip.238* I become `Host unreachable`.

How could I configure the routing so the internal traffic only goes through `enp1`? Say when server A wants to communicate to server B using the IP of `enp0`  the traffic goes only through `enp1`.

route -n :

```
  Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

  0.0.0.0       public.ip.193   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0
  0.0.0.0       public.ip.193   0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 enp0
  169.254.0.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 enp0
  priv.ip.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     102    0        0 enp1
  public.ip.192 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     101    0        0 enp0
  public.ip.193 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 enp0
```

Comment: Could you append the result of `ip route` from one of your hosts? I guess there are some routes missing.

Comment: Done! i have noticed that a little bit later after commenting

Comment: So pinging between the `enp0` is intendet to work but does not? To me, it seems like it does not work and you try to get around by routing the traffic via `enp1` or am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: the Servers should actually communicate internally using `enp1`. But i want to install Openshift (enhanced Kubernetes Cluster) so all the services should be reachable on `enp0` and i don't know how to tell the servers that internally they should use `enp1` to communicate

Comment: Ok so you want to route traffic between the public addresses via the private interfaces. Why do you want to do that, are you having security concerns? Usually one would make the services listen on the private IP as well as the public IP so you can use the private IPs for requesting the service internally. You could even use a private `DNS` server to let the `FQDN` point to the private IP.

Answer (score 0):

The following has been tested on Ubuntu machines, I am not sure if it is going to work on RedHat related systems at (your) default settings.

In order to route the public IPs of the other hosts via the private interfaces, perform the following:

**On server A**

```
ip -4 route add public.ip.237 dev enp1
ip -4 route add public.ip.238 dev enp1
```

**On server B**

```
ip -4 route add public.ip.237 dev enp1
ip -4 route add public.ip.239 dev enp1
```

**On server C**

```
ip -4 route add public.ip.238 dev enp1
ip -4 route add public.ip.239 dev enp1
```

**Note that this configuration is not persistent** and will be flushed on reboot. Nevertheless, this gives you the opportunity to try out whether this is the setting you want to keep. If this is not wat you want you can simply reboot or run the same commands after replacing the `add` with `del` in order to remove routes.

Depending on what tool you use to make network configuration, you need to adapt the settings in order to have them permanent and survive reboots.